# TextIOWrapper gzip buffer dropping records at the end even with flush

Tags: python, io, gzip

I'm having an issue where writing to the gzip buffer drops records at the end.

```
print(f'Data has {len(data)} rows')

    try:
        with gzip.GzipFile(mode="w", fileobj=gz_buffer) as gz_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(TextIOWrapper(gz_file, "utf8"), fieldnames=data[0].keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            for i, row in enumerate(data):
                writer.writerow(row)
            print(f"{len(data)} records written")  # Log each record
            gz_file.flush() 
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error writing record {e}")
        
        raise e

    gz_buffer.seek(0)  # Important: seek back to the start of the buffer
    with gzip.GzipFile(mode="r", fileobj=gz_buffer) as gz_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(TextIOWrapper(gz_file, "utf8"))
        record_count = sum(1 for row in reader)  # Count records

    print(f"Number of records in the buffer: {record_count}")

    import tempfile

    try:
        # Create a temporary file
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+b", suffix=".gz", delete=False) as temp_file:
            with gzip.GzipFile(mode="w", fileobj=temp_file) as gz_file:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(TextIOWrapper(gz_file, "utf8"), fieldnames=data[0].keys())
                writer.writeheader()
                for i, row in enumerate(data):
                    writer.writerow(row)
                    #print(f"Record {i} written")
                gz_file.close()

            temp_file_path = temp_file.name
            print(f"Temporary file created at: {temp_file_path}")

        # Read from the temporary file
        with gzip.open(temp_file_path, 'rt') as gz_file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(gz_file)
            record_count = sum(1 for row in reader)

        print(f"Number of records in the temporary file: {record_count}")
```

outout

```
Data has 4598 rows
4598 records written
Number of records in the buffer: 4587
Temporary file created at: /var/folders/v8/hs0gswcx4459zbsz8zskbkz40000gr/T/tmpxf9nlmt6.gz
Number of records in the temporary file: 4587
```

If I write to s3 there is only 4587 records. What am I missing? Do I need to do something else to make sure the data currently in the buffer gets written to? It seems to 'offload' every 10-15 records, so those are currently being lost. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by [`TextIOWrapper` being buffered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

In this part of your code

```py
    try:
        with gzip.GzipFile(mode="w", fileobj=gz_buffer) as gz_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(TextIOWrapper(gz_file, "utf8"), fieldnames=data[0].keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            for i, row in enumerate(data):
                writer.writerow(row)
            print(f"{len(data)} records written")  # Log each record
            gz_file.flush() 
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error writing record {e}")
```

The `writer` will write into `DictWriter`, which writes into `TextIOBuffer`, which buffers its content, and then writes into `gz_files`. When the last record has been written, the `context` for `gz_file` ends (the `gz_file.flush` is ueless btw, the context already does that), and no data can be written any more. But the `TextIOWrapper` still has data buffered; since it is not destroyed until the very end of the scope, that data is lost without anyone noticing.

You'd probably get some sort of `ResourceWarning` if you ran this code with warnings enabled, as the `TextIOWrapper` will only notice that it can't write its buffer to the underlying stream when it is being garbage-collected much later on.

The solution is to either `.flush()` the `TextIOWrapper` before the `gz_file`-context ends, or - as you have at least two layers of buffering anyway - create the `TextIOWrapper` with `write_through=True` to avoid any buffering.

The exact same problem occurs a second time, further down in the code.

Comment: So I was flushing the wrong buffer then? I changed to setting text_wrapper = TextIOWrapper(gz_file, "utf8") and then doing text_wrapper.flush() instead of gz_file.flush() and it now is writing all records thanks!

Comment: @LXandor, yes, you were flushing a stream (`gz_file`) which another unflushed stream (the unbound `TextIOBuffer`) was writing into